# Trying to create D3 + AngularJS Bar Chart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to create a D3 Bar chart with angularjs. This is my directive, and currently I am having a couple of problems.

1. The chart is not appended to the directives div, but to html tag
2. Chart is appended multiple times, even though when watch is called, we only log one append
3. When loggin d3.select(jqElm[0]), it outputs the directives element

What am I doing wrong?

```js
(function (angular, d3) {
    'use strict';

    var isDef = angular.isDefined,
        aExtend = angular.extend,
        aCopy = angular.copy,
        isArray = angular.isArray,
        isObject = angular.isObject,
  aElement = angular.element,
  isEqual = angular.equals;

    angular.module('Widgets.Module')
        .factory('ConstructorD3Bar', Constructor)
        .directive('tmD3Bar', Directive);

 Constructor.$inject = [
  'Common'
 ];

 Directive.$inject = [
  'Common',
  'ConstructorD3Bar'
 ];

    function Constructor(Common) {
        var cgenerator = Common.Generator;

        function D3Bar(attrs) {
            this._setProps(attrs);
        }

        D3Bar.prototype = {
            _setProps: function (p) {
                p = p || {};

    this.id = isDef(p.id) ? p.id : cgenerator.id;
    this.theme = isDef(p.theme) ? p.theme : 'D3Bar';
    this.message = isDef(p.message) ? p.message : 'D3Bar';
                this.data = isDef(p.data) ? p.data : [];
                this.format = isDef(p.format) ? p.format : null;
                this.tsv = isDef(p.tsv) ? p.tsv : null;
                this.csv = isDef(p.csv) ? p.csv : null;

                this.margin = isDef(p.margin) ? p.margin : { top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0};
                this.boxWidth = isDef(p.boxWidth) ? p.boxWidth : Common.$window.innerWidth;
                this.boxHeight = isDef(p.boxHeight) ? p.boxHeight : Common.$window.innerHeight;
                this.width = isDef(p.width) ? p.width : Common.$window.innerWidth;
                this.height = isDef(p.height) ? p.height : Common.$window.innerHeight;

                this.init();
            },
            init: function () {
                var that = this;

                if (that.tsv !== null) {
                    d3.tsv(that.tsv, function (err, data) {

                        if (isDef(err) && err && err.status) {
                            switch (err.status) {
                            case 404:
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        that.data = data;
                    });
                }
            },
            toString: function () {
                return this;
            }
        };

        return {
            create: function (props) {
                return new D3Bar(props);
            }
        };
    }

    function Directive(
  Common,
  ConstructorD3Bar
 ) {
        var directive = {
   templateUrl: 'widgets/d3-charts/bar/bar.tpl.html',
            controller: ctrl,
            compile: compile,
            scope: {
                attrs: '=?'
            },
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'AC'
        };
        return directive;

        function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {
   return {
    pre: function (scope, jqElm, attr) {
                    scope.initWidget = function () {
                        if (!isDef(scope.attrs) || scope.attrs === null) {
                            scope.attrs = ConstructorD3Bar.create({});
                        }

                        var margin = scope.attrs.margin,
                            width = scope.attrs.boxWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
                            height = scope.attrs.boxHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                        scope.attrs.width = width;
                        scope.attrs.height = height;

                        var formatPercent = d3.format('.0%');

                        scope.attrs.x = d3.scale
                            .ordinal()
                            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1, 1);

                        scope.attrs.y = d3.scale
                            .linear()
                            .range([height, 0]);

                        scope.attrs.xAxis = d3.svg
                            .axis()
                            .scale(scope.attrs.x)
                            .orient('bottom');

                        scope.attrs.yAxis = d3.svg
                            .axis()
                            .scale(scope.attrs.y)
                            .orient('left')
                            .tickFormat(formatPercent);
                    };
    },
    post: function (scope, jqElm, attr) {
     scope.$on('$destroy', function () { });

                    scope.$watch(
                        function () {
                            return scope.attrs.data;
                        },
                        function (nValue, oValue) {
                            if (!nValue) {
                                return;
                            }

                            if (nValue.length === 0) {
                                return;
                            }

                            var data = nValue;

                            scope.attrs.svg = d3.select(jqElm[0])
                                .data(data)
                                .enter()
                                .append('svg')
                                .attr('width', scope.attrs.width + scope.attrs.margin.left + scope.attrs.margin.right)
                                .attr('height', scope.attrs.height + scope.attrs.margin.top + scope.attrs.margin.bottom)
                                .append('g')
                                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + scope.attrs.margin.left + ',' + scope.attrs.margin.top + ')');

                            data.forEach(function (d) {
                                d.frequency = +d.frequency;
                            });

                            scope.attrs.x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
                                return d.letter;
                            }));
                            scope.attrs.y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                                return d.frequency;
                            })]);

                            scope.attrs.svg.append('g')
                                .attr('class', 'x axis')
                                .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + scope.attrs.height + ')')
                                .call(scope.attrs.xAxis);

                            scope.attrs.svg.append('g')
                                .attr('class', 'y axis')
                                .call(scope.attrs.yAxis)
                                .append('text')
                                .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
                                .attr('y', 6)
                                .attr('dy', '.71em')
                                .style('text-anchor', 'end')
                                .text('Frequency');

                            scope.attrs.svg.selectAll('.bar')
                                .data(data)
                                .enter().append('rect')
                                .attr('class', 'bar')
                                .attr('x', function (d) {
                                    return scope.attrs.x(d.letter);
                                })
                                .attr('width', scope.attrs.x.rangeBand())
                                .attr('y', function (d) {
                                    return scope.attrs.y(d.frequency);
                                })
                                .attr('height', function (d) {
                                    return scope.attrs.height - scope.attrs.y(d.frequency);
                                });
                        }
                    );
    }
   };
        }

        function ctrl($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var vm = $scope;

   if (!isDef(vm.attrs) || vm.attrs === null) {
    vm.attrs = ConstructorD3Bar.create({ });
   }

   var attrs = vm.attrs;
  }
    }
})(window.angular, window.d3);
```

```html
<div id="{{ attrs.id }}" class="D3Bar" ng-class="attrs.theme" ng-init="initWidget()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove .data().enter in .select

```js
scope.attrs.svg = d3.select(jqElm[0])
.append('svg')
.attr('width', scope.attrs.width + scope.attrs.margin.left + scope.attrs.margin.right)
.attr('height', scope.attrs.height + scope.attrs.margin.top + scope.attrs.margin.bottom)
.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + scope.attrs.margin.left + ',' + scope.attrs.margin.top + ')');
```